# MyBatis resultMap with a Builder in the POJO

Tags: java, mybatis

Suppose I have a java class representing a Person which uses a builder pattern:

```
package com.xyz.domain;

public class Person {

    private final int id;
    private final String firstName;
    private final String middleName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final String address;
    private final String country;

    private Person(PersonBuilder builder) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = builder.firstName;
        this.middleName = builder.middleName;
        this.lastName = builder.lastName;
        this.address = builder.address;
        this.country = builder.country;
    }

    // getters go here

    public static class PersonBuilder {

        private int id;
        private final String firstName;
        private final String lastName;

        private String middleName;
        private String address;
        private String country;

        public PersonBuilder(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.id = id;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public PersonBuilder withMiddleName(String middleName) {
            this.middleName = middleName;
            return this;
        }

        public PersonBuilder withAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
            return this;
        }

        public PersonBuilder withCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
            return this;
        }

        public Person build() {
            return new Person(this);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to use this as the `type` in a mybatis `resultMap` as so:

```
<resultMap id="Person" type="com.xyz.domain.Person">
    <id property="id" column="id" />
    <result property="firstName" column="first_name" />
    <result property="middleName" column="middle_name" />
    <result property="lastName" column="last_name" />
    <result property="address" column="address" />
    <result property="country" column="country" />
</resultMap>
```

This, however, yields a 500 error in my Spring app when I call an endpoint which uses this result map. I've also tried setting the `type` parameter in the `resultMap` to `com.xyz.domain.Person.PersonBuilder` and also get an error. Is there any way to make this work without sacrificing the builder pattern in the Person class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by updating the result map like so

```
<resultMap id="Person" type="com.xyz.domain.Person$PersonBuilder">
    <constructor>
        <idArg name="id" column="id" />
        <arg name="firstName" column="first_name" />
        <arg name="lastName" column="last_name" />
    </constructor>
    <result property="middleName" column="middle_name" />
    <result property="address" column="address" />
    <result property="country" column="country" />
</resultMap>
```

This creates a List of PersonBuilder objects, but it was easy enough to iterate through that list and call the `build()` method on each list item in java: `personBuilderList.stream().map(Person.PersonBuilder::build).collect(toList())`

Answer (score 0):

Mark the POJO with @Alias("Person") annotation.
And also make sure that the package com.xyz.domain is included to scan POJOs while configuring myBatis data connection.